# Retrieve argument prior to vertical bar ( | )

Tags: php, shell

I'm making a word solver and I'm trying to get access to the argument put in prior to the vertical bar | , which has a php command afterwards.

I would be running a command like "echo –e “word\ngame” | php wordsearch.php table.txt", for example. I want to get the contents of echo so I can run the contents and try to find them in a table of words, like the word search game.

In other words, I need to retrieve the "echo -e "word\ngame" part so I can use it in the wordsearch.php program.

Comment: You need to get the output of echo as a argument of php ?

Comment: Yes, I need to retrieve the "echo -e "word\ngame" part so I can use it in the wordsearch.php program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

while($line = fgets($f)) {
  echo $line;
}

fclose($f);
```

which will result in:

```
> echo "yo" | php foo.php 
> yo
```

Comment: This retrieves standard input, not the actual command which produced the input.